# Is it possible to customize Windows 8.1 colors similarly to how it was since Win95 in the "Advanced Appearance Settings"?

Tags: windows-8.1, colors, desktop-customization

For the first time since Windows 95, Windows 8/8.1 ceased to offer the "Advanced Appearance Settings", which enabled the following customizations:

[image: screenshot of the "Window Color and Appearance" window]

That is a shame, not only because users lost customization power, but specifically because it made much more difficult for an user to set its own dark-theme version of the system.

Is there any way to change such colors in Windows 8.1? Notice that I am not talking about merely doing [this](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/29573-color-background-accent-force-windows-8-1-a.html) and I also am not talking about patching the Windows to use customized 3rd party themes. I talking about a way for users to customize the colors of the windows in Windows 8.1 (trough registry, trough hidden options, trough a third party software that tries to recover such lost options, etc).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The Advanced Appearance Settings dialog was removed in Windows 8, but there is a [3rd party replacement](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/163836-advanced-appearance-settings-for-windows-8/)

[image]

But for the default Windows Theme, changing color is not supported since Vista.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was excited to see that someone tried to bring some of those options back, but there are two problems: 1) the link for downloading such an app is no longer working; 2) the color-changing functionality, which is the only I was looking after, seems to not have been implemented.

Comment: ok, I 've uploaded the version of the tool I had on my drive on my dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vowwhswuh3pexyy/Advanced%20Appearance%20Settings.zip?dl=1 changing the color doesn't work. you need 3rd party themes

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Well, but that is the catch: if custom themes are a possibility (and it's pretty easy to find a bunch of them), there has to be a way to make them, right? In other words, there has to be a way to change colors.

Comment: this is complicated. you need to buy a 3rd party tool to create themes: https://www.win7stylebuilder.com/download.html#download

Answer (score 1):

You could download [Winaero Tweaker](http://winaero.com/comment.php?comment.news.1836). It lets you adjust most of the advanced appearance parameters that still work with modern Windows theme.

[image: Screenshot of Winaero Tweaker]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you use the [Classic theme](http://winclassic.boards.net/board/3/classic-theme-general)

You will get something like the following:
[image]

You can then change the colors using registry:

[image]